# Zend_Form: Wrap html tags around subforms

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-sub-form

Say I have this form:

```
$this->addElement('select', 'menu');

$subform = new Zend_Form_SubForm();
$subform->addElement('text', 'title');
$subform->addElement('text', 'content');

$this->addSubform($subform, 'bar');

$this->addElement('submit', 'submit');
```

And I wanted to wrap custom html around the subform like:

```
<div id="foo">
     <!-- subform here -->
</div>
```

How would I go about to do that? `addSubform()` does not take an option parameter like `addElement()` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can a decorators to subforms.

```
$subform-> setSubFormDecorators($decorators);
```